# How to disable default keyCode event in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I press the enter key on `p:inputText` field then automatically triggered `p:commandButton`. This is not the behaviour I want.

How can I disable the automated triggering?

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: I used 3 three <p:inputText> in my page,when i press the enter key on my 2nd <p:inputText> then the <p:commandButton> should be call.this is need.

Comment: But, my problem is when I entered key on 1st <p:inputText> then automatically called <p:commandButton> for save.

Comment: I used onkeyPressed="--" in my 2nd <p:inputText> but when I entered 1st <p:inputText> its also called <p:commandButton>.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behaviour by return false in the `onkeypress` attribute on your `h:form`.

```
<h:form onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;">
```

13 is the key code corresponding to "Enter"

However, this snippet can break your `textarea` (you want users to be able to hit Enter to get a new line) so I would improve the above snippet and define a custom JS function.

**.xhtml**

```
<h:form onkeypress="return doNotSubmitFormOnEnterPress(event)">
```

**.js**

```
function doNotSubmitFormOnEnterPress(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13 && !$(event.target).is('textarea')) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```